# Error : 5 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns but dimensions are not wrong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame([[12.794, 13.8],
              [10.344, 13.356],
              [10.521, 11.235],
              [10.944, 14.978],
              [10.374, 10.73]],
             columns =['D6:4B:4C:E4:AE:29',
                       'ED:80:60:21:F4:ED',
                       'D1:7C:82:85:52:50',
                       'EA:CC:3B:08:72:06',
                       'C8:8F:56:44:4C:72'])
```

returns :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\", line 369, in __init__
    arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\", line 6284, in _to_arrays
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\", line 6363, in _list_to_arrays
    coerce_float=coerce_float)
  File "C:\", line 6420, in _convert_object_array
    'columns' % (len(columns), len(content)))
AssertionError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns
```

I have 5 columns and 5 rows...
I tried with 3 columns and 3 rows and it works.

Please, I would like a clarification.
Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this,

```
d = np.array([[12.794, 13.8], [10.344, 13.356], [10.521, 11.235], [10.944, 14.978], [10.374, 10.73]])
columns =['D6:4B:4C:E4:AE:29', 'ED:80:60:21:F4:ED', 'D1:7C:82:85:52:50', 'EA:CC:3B:08:72:06', 'C8:8F:56:44:4C:72']
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(columns, d)))
```

O/P:

```
  C8:8F:56:44:4C:72  D1:7C:82:85:52:50  D6:4B:4C:E4:AE:29  EA:CC:3B:08:72:06  \
0             10.374             10.521             12.794             10.944   
1             10.730             11.235             13.800             14.978   

   ED:80:60:21:F4:ED  
0             10.344  
1             13.356
```

Explanation:

`zip` the contents of `values` and `header` and convert into zip. then pass this in to `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

Your shape of the data structure is not proper. You are giving in 5rows and 2 columns. I believe you want it as 2rows and 5colums.

```
arr=np.array([[12.794, 13.8], [10.344, 13.356], [10.521, 11.235], [10.944, 14.978], [10.374, 10.73]])
pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(np.array(arr),(2,5)),columns =['D6:4B:4C:E4:AE:29', 'ED:80:60:21:F4:ED', 'D1:7C:82:85:52:50', 'EA:CC:3B:08:72:06', 'C8:8F:56:44:4C:72'])
```